# Getting a file URL from Sanity out of a blocks array

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity, groq

I'm building a website using Next JS and Sanity for the CMS. Sanity has built-in schemas for images but not for video, so a video needs to be uploaded with the File schema. [The docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/file-type) suggest that to get a file URL to be used on the front-end you should use the query language GROQ to make this conversion at the request like so:

```
// GROQ query
*[_type == 'movie'] {
  title,
  "manuscriptURL": manuscript.asset->url
}
```

But since I am using the File schema to embed short auto-looping videos into rich text content using the Blocks schema, I don't have the luxury of converting URLs at the request and need to do it dynamically as the blocks array data is being parsed for the `@portabletext/react` component.

Basically, what I get back for the file is simply an asset reference with the following data:

```
{
    "_type": "file",
    "asset": {
        "_ref": "file-e4e61f3b231cca8e3339e96e050aee428009c777-gif",
        "_type": "reference"
    }
}
```

When I then use Sanity's own `@sanity/asset-utils` package to get a file URL using their `buildFileUrl()` function, I get a URL that is undefined for that asset where PROJECT_ID and DATASET are the correct values:
`https://cdn.sanity.io/files/[PROJECT_ID]/[DATASET]/undefined.undefined`

Here is the function I made, using their package's file URL function, to get the asset URL, which returns the URL above with the undefined values:

```
export function getSanityFileUrl(sanityFile) {
  const fileUrl = buildFileUrl(sanityFile.asset, {projectId: sanityConfig.projectId, dataset: sanityConfig.dataset})
  console.log(fileUrl)
}
```

Thanks and anything helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The `buildFileUrl()` function exported by `@sanity/asset-utils` expects a different asset object. Instead, a user in this situation should use the `getFileAsset()` function which can accept a reference to the file.